# MAC hanged when submitting app

Tags: iphone, mac, applications, ios, app-store-connect

I've submitted my first app to Apple and waiting for approval. My MAC was hanged while I was submitting. I needed to restart MAC. After restarting, the state of app on iTunes connect was 'Waiting For Review'. I am not sure whether binary was uploaded correctly or not. Will Apple Review Team contact me in case binary was not uploaded properly? If yes, how much time it usually takes?

Answer (score 1):

**Waiting for Review** is the status after **Waiting for Upload**, this means your binary should have been uploaded correctly.

However, to be certain - why wouldn't you revoke it and upload it again?
Else you have to wait and maybe get a result that the binary is corrupted and you have to wait the *usually pretty long* period again.

Comment: OK. I'll try to revoke it and upload again. 
Thanks..!!